Unix Replace Function
How to replace my file containing records that is delimited by , (asterisk, comma, asterisk) to pipe?
Thank you very much!
Here is the sample data:
0123456789","WLAN","0123456","012345678","1.00","AB","ABCD EFGHIJ","0123

Expected output is:
0123456789|WLAN|0123456|012345678|1.00|AB|ABCD EFGHIJ|0123

I have already tried sed, awk and perl but to no avail. This file contains around 50M records.

I have already tried sed, awk and perl - Please include whatever you have tried in the question itself.

Your sample data appears to missing starting and ending quotes.

That's not an "asterisk".  That's a double quote.  Is this a regular need, or a one-time need?  You could do this in any text editor almost instantly.

Using sed with a character set:
$ sed -E 's/[,"]+/|/g' file
0123456789|WLAN|0123456|012345678|1.00|AB|ABCD EFGHIJ|0123


Maybe note if input contains empty fields then they will not appear in the output (data loss)?

@AllanWind .. what?

The input a","","b will generate the output a|b so the input field 2 was deleted, and you cannot tell after fact which field was which.

@AllanWind we can only work with the information we are given

If the delimiter includes the quotes:
sed 's/","/|/g' <<<'0123456789","WLAN","0123456","012345678","1.00","AB","ABCD EFGHIJ","0123'
0123456789|WLAN|0123456|012345678|1.00|AB|ABCD EFGHIJ|0123


The following assumes that the missing double quotes at the beginning and at the end of your example input line are just typos.
If your input is true CSV (with double-quoted fields that may contain doubled double-quotes, commas or newlines), and if you have a recent enough version of GNU awk (at least 5.3.0), you can try:
awk -k -v OFS='|' '{$1 = $1} 1' foo.csv
0123456789|WLAN|0123456|012345678|1.00|AB|ABCD EFGHIJ|0123

Note that if your input contains pipe characters you should define an output format that supports this. Else the result will probably not be what you want.

What does the -k do (it's not in 5.2.1)?

It parses CSV format and splits the fields accordingly. This was introduced in 5.3.0. See this for the details.
